# Chrome Extensions: Any way to tell when a key is pressed and held?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing an extension for chrome that takes action based on shortcut keys for specific web pages. Right now I'm using the "command" API to tell when a shortcut key is pressed ( https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands ). Is there any way to tell if a key is pressed and held? I only want this specific action to take place when that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

jQuery Hotkeys lets you watch for keyboard events anywhere in your code supporting almost any key combination.

Answer (score 0):

There are some keyboard events api, which can be only accessed in the context of the web page ( for chrome extension, you should listen to them in content scripts), such as [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)